# how to center snackbar message in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to figure out how I can make my snackbar message to be center but not really sure how to do that without removing duration. I tried to remove the empty action but when I do that it gave me error. I would be appreciate if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

  subscribeUpdateChartResult(){
    this.chartService.chartUpdated.subscribe(updated=>{
      if(updated){
        this.snackbar.open("Chart has been updated", " ", {duration: 2500});
      }else{
        this.snackbar.open("Errors, Could not updated", " ", {duration: 2500});
      }
    })
  }
```

When I do like this

```
this.snackbar.open("Chart has been updated", {duration: 2500});
```

I get this error on duraction;

```
Argument of type '{ duration: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

[image]

Comment: If you can give us a https://stackblitz.com/ example of your error,  write the code there so we can see and try to modify and figure out the problem.

Comment: The 2nd parameter is used to specify the snack bar's action text. If you want to not specify any text, pass `null` instead.

Comment: @Edric actually `null` will result in an error in a `strict: true` typescript environment, because it expects either a `string` of `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center align the text of the snackbar you need to add a global style to override the material styling:

```
.mat-simple-snackbar {
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

And to pass in an empty action, you can use either `void 0` or `undefined`:

```
this._snackBar.open(message, void 0, {
  duration: 5000,
});
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmndau?file=src/app/snack-bar-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You should inset to config snakerbar like this  for change position  snakerbar

```
 this.snackBar.open('im a massage', 'close', {
      duration: 10000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
    });
  }
```

**verticalPosition** Specifies vertical position and  **horizontalPosition** Specifies horizontal position, I write sample snakerBar positions look at this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material)

Answer (score 0):

can you try in style.css  [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-snackbar-2jmqpm) .For these kind of css things you can use developer console and inspect elements then in global.css change its style how you want.

```
.mat-simple-snackbar {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="cdk-overlay-container">
    <div class="cdk-global-overlay-wrapper" dir="ltr" style="justify-content: center; align-items: flex-end;">
        <div id="cdk-overlay-0" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="pointer-events: auto; position: static; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <snack-bar-container class="mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c96-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-state mat-snack-bar-center ng-star-inserted" role="alert" style="transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;">
                <simple-snack-bar class="mat-simple-snackbar ng-star-inserted"><span>Thank you!</span>
                    <div class="mat-simple-snackbar-action ng-star-inserted">
                        <button mat-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">×</span>
                            <div matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div>
                            <div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </simple-snack-bar>
            </snack-bar-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my solution is following:

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane {
    margin-bottom: calc(50vh - 50px)!important;
}
```

where `50px` is a half of message height